# In kivy, how to get the duration of a button click

Tags: python, user-interface, button, kivy

I need to perform an action based on the amount of seconds the user clicks the button.

```
def add_day(self,ins):
        for i in range(<click Time>):
               cur=datetime.datetime.strptime(self.date_lb.text,'%d %b %Y').date()
               dt=cur+day
               self.date_lb.text=dt.strftime('%d %b %Y')
```

Here I increase the date by unity 
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

You can use a callback method for the `on_press` event of a `Button`, that records the press time to a variable.
Then you can use another callback method for the `on_release` event of the same `Button`, to get the release time and subtract it from the previous variable.